# Issue when trying to use the rodio audio crate with a glutin event loop closure

Tags: rust, closures, clone, move-semantics, ownership

I have a glutin window and OpenGL context and am trying to add sound to my program. I stumbled upon rodio as it seemed the best fit for my project.
Following the docs, I wrote a helper function for loading a file as a sound source and implemented it in my program:

```rust
use rodio::Decoder;
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::BufReader,
    error:Error
}

fn load_sound_file(path: &str) -> Result<Decoder<BufReader<File>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    // load a sound from a file
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(path)?);

    // decode that sound into a source
    let source = Decoder::new(file)?;

    Ok(source)
}

use glutin::event_loop::EventLoop;
use rodio::{ OutputStream, Sink };

fn main() {
    let el = EventLoop::new();
    ...
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();
    let sink = Sink::try_new(&stream_handle).unwrap();

    let beep_sound = load_sound_file("beep.ogg").unwrap();
    ...

    el.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        sink.append(beep_sound);
        ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't work however, as the compiler complains that it `` cannot move out of `beep_sound`, a captured variable in an FnMut closure `` because `beep_sound` has type `Decoder<BufReader<File>>` which doesn't implement the `Copy` trait.
I then tried using a clone of `beep_sound`:

```rust
...
el.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
    let beep_clone = beep_sound.clone();
    sink.append(beep_clone);
    ...
}
```

But then the compiler complains that there's `` no method named `clone` found for struct `Decoder<BufReader<File>>` in the current scope ``.
I'm still inexperienced when it comes to Rust closures and ownership and some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used rodio before, but from looking at the docs, it almost seems like you are expected to create a new `Decoder` every time you want to play a sound. You can of course load the file from the file system once at the start. But again, I'm not sure. You could maybe ask on their issue tracker.

Comment: This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990103/9353072).